# Error al instalar wordpress. Muestra setup despues de instalar

Tags: wordpress, nginx

He instalado wordpress sobre un dominio. Puedo entrar a la administracion del dominio sin embargo cuando entro a mi dominio principal sigue apareciendo el setup cuando debe aparecerme la página:

Welcome to WordPress. Before getting started, we need some information on the database. You will need to know the following items before proceeding.

¿Es necesario realizar alguna corrección? Menciono que estoy usando nginx y php-fpm ya que quiero montar varios dominios con php, nodejs y angular

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado para resolverlo?¿qué resultados has obtenido? Con la información que aportas, lo único que se me ocurre decirte es que lo vuelvas a instalar, pero no sé si ya lo has hecho. Ves aportando información a ver si podemos ayudarte

Comment: Se solucionó al reiniciar el servidor. De alguna forma se quedó con un caché.
En un inicio pensé que era por un tema del nginx o algún parámetro que no se estaba pasando al redirigir del nginx hacia el php-fpm.
Gracias por el apoyo

Answer (score 0):

Debes revisar que la copia de la base de datos sea correcta y sin errores.
Luego vete al archivo .htaccess y revisa que no haya ningún link, como por ejemplo localhost. Es decir, si en .htacces aparece esto así:

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /carpeta/tudomino/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /carpeta/tudominio/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Tendria que quedar asi:

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

También es muy importante que tu archivo wp-config.php este de manera correcta con el nombre del dominio, servidor, user, etc.

Normalmente eso es lo que falla al exportar un wordpress a un dominio. También asegúrate de que todos los archivos se hayan enviado de forma correcta por ftp.